# Kernel error when trying to start an NFS server in a container

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I was trying to run through the NFS example in the Kubernetes codebase on Container Engine, but I couldn't get the shares to mount. Turns out every time the nfs-server pod is launched, the kernel is throwing an error:

Apr 27 00:11:06 k8s-cluster-6-node-1 kernel: [60165.482242] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Apr 27 00:11:06 k8s-cluster-6-node-1 kernel: [60165.483060] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 7160 at /build/linux-50mAO0/linux-3.16.7-ckt4/fs/nfsd/nfs4recover.c:1195 nfsd4_umh_cltrack_init+0x4a/0x60 nfsd

Full output here: http://pastebin.com/qLzCFpAa

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The NFS example doesn't work because GKE (by default) doesn't support running privileged containers, such as the nfs-server. I just tested this with a v0.16.0 cluster and kubectl v0.15.0 (the current gcloud default) and got a nice error message when I tried to start the nfs-server pod:

```
$ kubectl create -f nfs-server-pod.yaml
Error: Pod "nfs-server" is invalid: spec.containers[0].privileged: forbidden 'true'
```

Comment: I edited the salt configuration to allow the pod to be created, which led to the warning.

Comment: How did you change the salt (I'd like to try and reproduce, because if you are tinkering with the salt configs you _should_ be able to get this to work).

Comment: Edit: `/srv/pillar/privilege.sls`, change `allow_privileged` to True. Run `salt-call state.highstate`, `then service kubelet restart`. This has to be done on the master and all nodes. Salt seems to restart the apiserver fine.